# Apple seedling stunted growth, stem reddish brown, soil smelling bad. Please help me!

Tags: indoors

I stay in an apartment in Kuwait and have an apple seedling of about 2 inches. I grow it indoors, planted it from a sprouted seed inside an apple, alll went well till it suddenly stopped growing. I added cinnamon powder and honey once to aid in anti-fungal properties and stimulate better root growth.. but a week later the soil started giving off a really bad stench... Like that of urine. I'm guessing it's from over watering, the bottom of the stem has become reddish brown.. Noticing all this, I removed my seedling from the soil last night and have temporarily kept it in water. Please advise me as to how I can go ahead planting it again. Please do advise on natural fertilizers that I can make at home.

Comment: As you see, home made fertilizers are very difficult to make: they are not yet stable. i advice you again using them indoor: the rotting processes generate not so healthy (for human) gases. So buy organic fertilizers, or do this outside. Which soil did you used? (for 2 inches seedling, you do not need fertilizers).

Answer (score 1):

Your plant, if it's still viable, is likely to do fine if you give it ample soil and no fertilizer.  It wants to become a tree.  So give it a pot that's at least 6-8" deep just to get it started.  Fill the pot with good dirt to within about an inch of the top of the pot.  Then don't fertilize it at all until it is well-established, maybe 4-8 months and after it has put on many new leaves!

If you really want to make fertilizer for it to have later, you can make vermicompost in an indoor bin.  That's quite a project.  Otherwise, I'd recommend buying fish emulsion.  But give the plant no more than the directions recommend.  Too much fertilizer hurts, not helps, plants.